# Assets starting from the root of the server (rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm using local Webrick server on my local machine everything is OK, but after uploading my project to remote server (unicorn + nginx) i had bug with assets path. Now its starting from the root of the server:

```
<link href="/var/www/rails/demo/assets/application-2432a9098f54da0c4d34883512814c4b.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My app is located in /var/www/rails/demo/

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is your production environment managed or independent?

Comment: I have full control of the server environment if you mean it. And I can show any configs wich can help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

It probably has the same problem on your local machine, only it works because this path is available locally.

Comment: On local machine i have no such server configuration. I only use webrick server for development and this path can not somehow appears there